# ошибка get запроса

Tags: java, http, httpclient

Хотел написать get запрос к одному сайту (http://www.interpals.net), а мне в ответе возвращается:

> "Oops! If you are seeing this, your browser isnot loading the page
>   correctly. Please try pressing Control-F5 to force reload the page."

Получаю 200 response.
Запрос делаю - просто копипаста параметров из get запроса из google-chrome. В чем может быть причина? спасибо! 
Код:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.CookieHandler;
import java.net.CookieManager;

public class HttpUrlConnectionExample2 {

    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url = "https://www.interpals.net";
        HttpUrlConnectionExample2 http = new HttpUrlConnectionExample2();
        CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
        String page = http.sendGet(url);
        if (page.contains("Oops")) {
            System.out.println("HAS OOPS");
        }
    }

    private String sendGet(String link) throws Exception {
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(link);
        request.addHeader("user-agent", USER_AGENT);
        request.addHeader("method", "GET");
        request.addHeader("path", "/index.php");
        request.addHeader("scheme", "https");
        request.addHeader("version", "HTTP/1.1");
        request.addHeader("accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        //request.addHeader("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");
        request.addHeader("accept-language", "ru,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6");
        request.addHeader("cache-control", "max-age=0");
        request.addHeader("upgrade-insecure-requests", "1");

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + link);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " +
                response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }

        System.out.println(result);
        return result.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Может быть, что сервер данного сайта отвечает только на браузерные запросы, то есть, если Вы делаете запрос не с браузера, он Вам не ответит

Comment: я заполняю параметры, как раз представляюсь браузером. разве нет?

Comment: У вас точно все заголовки правильно написаны?

Comment: ну видимо что-то не правильно, раз не работает:( скрин с гугл-хрома: 
http://cs633428.vk.me/v633428031/14283/cOvDZsI-dEk.jpg

Comment: Попробуйте через http и без www

Answer (score 4):

Это не ошибка. Это просто просто дополнительный текстовый блок для владельцев устаревших браузеров, который всегда присутствует на любой странице:

```
<div id="browserWarning">
    <div style="width: 400px; margin: 40px auto; border: 3px solid #ddd; font-size: 15px;">
        <b>Error:</b> Oops! If you are seeing this, your browser is
        not loading the page correctly. Please try pressing Control-F5 to force reload
        the page. If this doesn't work, you may need to update your browser: <br><a href="http://www.getfirefox.com">Download Firefox</a> | <a href="http://www.google.com/chrome">Download Chrome</a> | <a href="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/default.aspx">Download
        IE</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Средствами CSS(`#browserWarning {display:none;}`) он по умолчанию не показывается в браузере. После загрузки страницы, если браузер не поддерживает требуемые этим сайтом возможности, посредством JavaScript этот блок делают видимым.

Вам тоже стоит просто проигнорировать этот блок в своём коде, сосредоточившись на получении необходимой вам информации.

Comment: т.е. мне просто возвразается настоящая страница + этот блок? на который мне просто забить? я просто случайно увидел этот блок, и решил, что у меня неправильно грузится страница. а как вообще проверить, что мне отдается точно тоже, что и браузеру? спасибо.

Comment: @Charm, Да, именно так - настоящая страница, включающая этот блок. Хотите проверить - сравните просто глазами. А вообще, лучше всегда исходить из того, присутствует ли на странице то, что вы хотите из неё извлечь, а не из того насколько она идентична отображаемому в браузере